# How can we find a product or category by incomplete name?

Tags: java, commercetools

I recently work with Commercetools platform and I have such a question. How we can find product or category and so on by incomplete name?

For example if in my url I wrote something like this

> `https://localhost:8080/cat?catName=G`

I wanna find all categories which contains a `G` . How we can done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this with a **categoryAutoComplete** query on the GraphQL API. The following query asks for categories beginning with "hi". You need to provide two characters at least, with one letter only it doesn't return any result.

```
{
  categoryAutocomplete(locale: "en", text: "hi") {
    results {
      name(locale: "en")
    }
  }
}
```

On my test project it this query returns two categories that have the term "hint" in their English name:

```
{
  "data": {
    "categoryAutocomplete": {
      "results": [
        {
          "name": "Test duplicate order hint"
        },
        {
          "name": "order hint test"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is this helpful?

Comment: Have you had a look at the JVM SDK docs: http://commercetools.github.io/commercetools-jvm-sdk/apidocs/io/sphere/sdk/meta/GraphQLDocumentation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make a GraphQL request with the commercetools JVM SDK as follows:

1. First implement the Java class representing your GraphQL response. So if one result object looks like:

```js
    {
      "name": "category name"
    }
```

Then the implementing java class `CategoryAutoCompleteResult` would look something like this:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.sphere.sdk.models.Base;

public class CategoryAutoCompleteResult extends Base {
    private final String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public CategoryAutoCompleteResult(@JsonProperty("name") final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

2. Then implement the GraphQL request class `CategoryAutoCompleteRequest`. This could be simplified by just implementing the `SphereRequest` interface from the commercetools JVM SDK as follows:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import io.sphere.sdk.client.HttpRequestIntent;
import io.sphere.sdk.client.SphereRequest;
import io.sphere.sdk.http.HttpMethod;
import io.sphere.sdk.http.HttpResponse;
import io.sphere.sdk.json.SphereJsonUtils;
import io.sphere.sdk.models.Base;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.List;


public class CategoryAutoCompleteRequest extends Base implements SphereRequest<List<CategoryAutoCompleteResult>> {
    private final String queryString;

    CategoryAutoCompleteRequest(final String queryString) {
        this.queryString = queryString;
    }

    public static CategoryAutoCompleteRequest of(@Nonnull final String queryString) {
        return new CategoryAutoCompleteRequest(queryString);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public List<CategoryAutoCompleteResult> deserialize(final HttpResponse httpResponse) {
        final JsonNode rootJsonNode = SphereJsonUtils.parse(httpResponse.getResponseBody());
        final JsonNode results = rootJsonNode.get("data").get("categoryAutocomplete").get("results");
        return SphereJsonUtils
            .readObject(results, new TypeReference<List<CategoryAutoCompleteResult>>() {
            });
    }

    @Override
    public HttpRequestIntent httpRequestIntent() {
        final String queryBody =
            String.format("{categoryAutocomplete(locale: \"en\", text: \"%s\") {results{name(locale: \"en\")}}}",
                queryString);
        final String graphQlQuery = buildGraphQlQuery(queryBody);


        return HttpRequestIntent.of(HttpMethod.POST, "/graphql", graphQlQuery);
    }

    private static String buildGraphQlQuery(@Nonnull final String queryBody) {
        return String.format("{ \"query\": \"%s\"}", queryBody.replace("\"", "\\\""));
    }
}
```

3. Then the last step would be to execute the actual request. Assuming you already have a setup `SphereClient`. Executing the request would looks as follows:

```java
final List<CategoryAutoCompleteResult> results = sphereClient
          .execute(CategoryAutoCompleteRequest.of("myIncompleteCatName")).toCompletableFuture().join();
```